# Pandas dataframe append to column containing list

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with one column that contains an empty list in each cell.

I need to duplicate the dataframe, and append it at the bottom of the original dataframe, but with additional information in the list.

Here is a minimal code example:

```
df_main = pd.DataFrame([['a', []], ['b', []]], columns=['letter', 'mylist'])
> df_main 
letter  mylist
0   a   []
1   b   []

df_copy = df_main.copy()
for index, row in df_copy.iterrows():
    row.mylist = row.mylist.append(1)

pd.concat([ df_copy,df_main], ignore_index=True)

> result:
letter  mylist
0   a   None
1   b   None
2   a   [1]
3   b   [1]
```

As you can see there is a problem that the [] empty list was replaced by a `None`

Just to make sure, this is what I would like to have:

```
letter  mylist
0   a   []
1   b   []
2   a   [1]
3   b   [1]
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`append` method on list return a `None` value, that's why `None` appears in the final dataframe. You may have use `+` operator for reassignment like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df_main = pd.DataFrame([['a', []], ['b', []]], columns=['letter', 'mylist'])

df_copy = df_main.copy()
for index, row in df_copy.iterrows():
    row.mylist = row.mylist + list([1])

pd.concat([df_main, df_copy], ignore_index=True).head()
```

Output of this block of code:

```
letter  mylist
0   a   []
1   b   []
2   a   [1]
3   b   [1]
```

Comment: This seems like the solution that I was looking for, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

A workaround to solve your problem would be to create a temporary column `mylist2` with `np.empty((len(df), 0)).tolist())` and use `np.where()` to change the `None` values of `mylist` to an empty list and then drop the empty column.

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
df_main = pd.DataFrame([['a', []], ['b', []]], columns=['letter', 'mylist'])
df_copy = df_main.copy()
for index, row in df_copy.iterrows():
    row.mylist = row.mylist.append(1)

df = (pd.concat([df_copy,df_main], ignore_index=True)
    .assign(mylist2=np.empty((len(df), 0)).tolist()))
df['mylist'] = np.where((df['mylist'].isnull()), df['mylist2'], df['mylist'])
df= df.drop('mylist2', axis=1)
df
Out[1]: 
  letter mylist
0      a     []
1      b     []
2      a    [1]
3      b    [1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not only does append method on list return a None value as indicated in the first answer, but both df_main  and df_copy  contain pointers to the same lists. So after:

```
for index, row in df_copy.iterrows():
    row.mylist.append(1)
```

both dataframes have updated lists with one element. For your code to work as expected you can create a new list after you copy the dataframe:

```
df_copy = df_main.copy()
for index, row in df_copy.iterrows():
    row.mylist = []
```

This question is another great example why we should not put objects in a dataframe.